# How to debug why my "Form Events Exercise" program is not working?

Tags: javascript

> Form Events Exercise
>
> Time to get some practice working with forms and form events! index.html already has a form element that contains two  elements, one for quantity and one for a product name.  index.html also contains an empty `<ul>` where you will append new `<li>`'s.  Watch the gif at the bottom for an overview of how your code should work. Your task is to follow these steps:
>
> Listen for the form submission
>
> When the form is submitted, prevent the default behavior
> Grab the quantity input value and the product input value
> Create a new `<li>` element.  Set the text on the new `<li>` to include the quantity and product name from the form.
> Append the new `<li>` to the `<ul>` on the page
> Reset the inputs
>
> Please note:
>
> 1. Udemy's interface does not yet recognize some of the newer JS syntax, e.g., `.append()`
>    You will need to use alternate (older) syntax for this method in order to get the tests to pass.
> 2. The form will need to be assigned to a variable named form for the test to pass, I've already included this line of code for you in the app.js code

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Grocery List</title>
    <!--LEAVE THESE LINES ALONE, PLEASE! THEY MAKE THE LIVE PREVIEW WORK!-->
    <script src="node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1>Grocery List</h1>
    <form action="/nowhere">
        <label for="item">Enter A Product</label>
        <input type="text" id="product" name="product">
        <label for="item">Enter A Quantity</label>
        <input type="number" id="qty" name="qty">
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>

    <ul id="list"></ul>
</body>

</html>
```

app.js

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const qty = document.querySelector('#qty');
const product = document.querySelector('#product');
const list = document.querySelector('#list');

    
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const productName = input.value;
    const qtyItem = input.value;
    const li = document.createElement('LI');
    
    li.innerText = product;
    li.innerText = qty;
    list.appendChild(product);
    list.appendChild(qty);
    
});
```

Comment: Please update your question and create a code snippets with HTML, JS, CSS.

Comment: I'm new at stackoverflow website so I'm sorry if my post kind of confuse you guys maybe i forgot to edit some contents or maybe i didn't know how to do it, I hope you folks got my question.

Comment: Look at your code for productName and qtyItem.  There is no variable `input`.  You probably meant product.value and qty.value.  From there, you'll need to rewrite the rest of the function to put text values in the LI, and not the dom elements.  Note that li.innerText = "thing1" follower by li.innerText = "thing2" will only display thing2.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also currently taking Colt's class. Here is my solution:

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const qty = document.querySelector('#qty');
const product = document.querySelector('#product');
const list = document.querySelector('#list');
        
            
form.addEventListener('submit', function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //change your input in input.value to the id set in the html 
    const productName = product.value;
    const qtyItem = qty.value;
    const li = document.createElement('LI');
        
    //this code: the second line will override the first line
    //li.innerText = product;
    //li.innerText = qty;
    //solution: join them
    li.innerText = qtyItem + " " + productName;
    list.appendChild(li);
    //add this line of code to empty the input after pressing submit
    product.value="";
    qty.value="";
           
});
```

Comment: A solution on its own with no explanation may not be very useful for the question author (or future readers). Could you edit this contribution with some explanation on how it solves the problem?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment. I'm new to overstackflow and coding. I have added some comments to explain my code, hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const product = document.querySelector('#product');
const quantity = document.querySelector('#qty');
const list = document.querySelector('#list');

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const text1 = product.value;
    const text2 = quantity.value;
    const newLI = document.createElement("li");

    newLI.innerText = `${text2} ${text1}`;
    list.appendChild(newLI);

    product.value = "";
    qty.value = "";
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).